# Wrap everything from certain div to certain div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a blog style layout in a cms so there are **multiple** instances of these divs.

This is the structure:

```
<div class="sfpostContent">
     <p>Some text</p>
     random text
     <p>Some text</p>
     <div class="sfpostsList-img">
         <img src="myimage.jpg"/>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="sfpostContent">
     <p>Some text</p>
     random text
     <p>Some text</p>
     <div class="sfpostsList-img">
         <img src="myimage.jpg"/>
     </div>
</div>
```

I want it to look like this:

```
    <div class="sfpostContent">
         <div class="sfpostsList-detail">
             <p>Some text</p>
             random text
             <p>Some text</p>
         </div>
         <div class="sfpostsList-img">
             <img src="myimage.jpg"/>
         </div>
    </div>
   <div class="sfpostContent">
         <div class="sfpostsList-detail">
             <p>Some text</p>
             random text
             <p>Some text</p>
         </div>
         <div class="sfpostsList-img">
             <img src="myimage.jpg"/>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Please note: I am already wrapping my image in `sfpostsList-img` via jquery

I want everything from **sfpostContent** to the start of **sfpostsList-img** wrapped in **sfpostsList-detail**

It is an fck editor so there's no telling what people will put in there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do it, but quick and dirty:

```
$('.sfpostContent').each(function() {
      var list_img = $(this).find('.sfpostsList-img');
      var list_img_html = list_img[0].outerHTML;
      list_img.remove();
      $(this).html('<div class="sfpostsList-detail">' + $(this).html() + '</div>' + list_img_html);
});
```

Comment: Any idea why this error is occuring with your code? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'outerHTML' of undefined

Comment: Yeah, change it to `var list_img_html = list_img[0] ? list_img[0].outerHTML : '';`

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
$('.sfpostsList-img').remove()
                     .appendTo($('.sfpostContent').wrapInner('<div class="sfpostsList-detail "></div>'));
```

For multiple, you could do:

```
$('.sfpostsList-img').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this), 
      target = $this.closest('.sfpostContent');
  $this.remove().appendTo(target.wrapInner('<div class="sfpostsList-detail "></div>'));
});
```

***[THE JSFIDDLE DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/T97jm/4/)***

Answer (score 0):

Use wrapAll

```
$("p").wrapAll('<div class="sfpostsList-detail"></div>');
```

Live demo->http://jsfiddle.net/T97jm/1/

Comment: There are multiple instances of these divs so all my blog posts are being wrapped in one div now. So that won't work. Also I don't want to target just 'p' tags - incase they put something else in the editor.

Comment: See ,you put your all contents inside one Div and then wrap the Div .Otherwise how come you know which elements are to be wrapped?

Comment: Well I thought there was a way to target everything from one class to right before the start of another class and wrap it. I've seen methods using nextUntil(); but I can't get it to work